# How can I put the same margin between columns on top and below if that columns have different heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this and i want a space like it the indicate in red.
I use bootstrap.

[myTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkqys.png)

EDIT: I want something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOtw.png), that always have the same margin with the other columns of top and bottom independent the height of columns, because all columns have different heights cause of the photo or description.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if it is possible through CSS. Checkout this javaScript plugin that does exactly what you want. [JavaScript Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit on the rough side, it's hard to explain. I did it up in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r2u8qsd4/).

CSS

```
    .container {
  column-width: 100px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

#card {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/519zImiZraL._SL500_AC_SS100_.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://saigonexpres.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Nokia-Asha-303-newshitechdigital-e1466994250562-100x75.png">
    </div>  

    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://linlona.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/samsung-a3-100x150.jpg">
    </div>  

    <div id="card">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wtdOTMfoL._SL500_AC_SS100_.jpg">
    </div>  

    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://www.hellkom.co.za/cellphones/images/small/samsung-galaxy-note-4-1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://www.price-hunt.com/content/images/accessories/mta-back-replacement-cover-for-lenovo-k-3-note.jpeg">
    </div>

    <div id="card">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qDcWYD6-L._SL500_AC_SS100_.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="card">
      <img src="http://www.mobile2u.com.pk/Images/Items/thumb/nokia_1112_image9034.bmp">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I can tell you is this, the key is in the column-width, column-gap, and most importantly, you need to make sure you set the margin-top of the cards to 0 so that they float as far top as they can. You can play around with it for different results. Good luck.